# Add timestamp to the transports file with Nodejs Winston daily transports in stream mode

Tags: node.js, winston

For fixing losing logs of transports file in high concurrency, I changed the mode to stream. Issue of losing logs was fixed then. But I have another problem that the transports file can not be created day by day(even I set the transports mode to `DailyRotateFile`).

I wanna know, is there any option can be set to implement this case? or I have to hack it???

Thanks guys.

Demo codes below:

```
new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
            level: 'info',
            stream: fs.createWriteStream('performance.log'),
        }))
    ]
});
```

Comment: If you remove the stream argument and add a filename, does the log rotate day by day? If so that would indicate to me that the DailyRotateFile only rotates by the filename and cannot rotate a file passed as a Stream, and you'd have to hack it personally.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, change the argument to filename works well, and its API provides this method. The reason by using stream is that I have to fix a problem - missing log when concurrency is very high. Haven't found any other way to fix it yet.